# Why can't I write to my USB Stick?

Tags: partitioning, usb, system-installation

I am trying to create a bootable USB Stick with Ubuntu 14.04 so I can install it on my computer, but for some reason, I get an authentication error:

[image: Authentication error]

I tried using Gnome Partition Editor to format the stick, and I deleted all partitions. I've tried ext4 and Fat32 partitions. Currently it is Fat32:

[image: gparted]

The permissions are not determinable, but I can't read or write any files to the USB stick:

[image: permissions]

It's just a regular 2GB USB stick:

[image: USB drive]

How do I get control over this USB stick so that I can write a bootable image to it?

Comment: With ubuntu usb stick maker, I had often problems. Try it with: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net

Comment: @FeritCubukcuoglu: That worked like a charm. Put that as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ubuntu usb stick maker, i had often problems. Try it with unetbootin.sourceforge.net ;)